# Having no idea of exporting a glb/gltf file with texture and animation properly

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, gltf, ocean-simulation

I am a newbie of Blender and kind of stuck in exporting a glb/ gltf file. I made an ocean simulation and tried to export it, but I don't know how to export a water texture, and the waterwaves animation is not exported successfully.  I know that I need to bake the texture of the ocean plane but I have no idea about how to create a UV for the plane that already been modified. I need some help of figuring out the problems. I attached some screenshots of my settings. Thanks so much[image]
[image]

Comment: The only thing you can animate in glTF is LocRotScale and shape key values. See the [manual page about glTF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html).

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures